# Efficiently selecting from subsets of a list

Tags: c#, list, performance, linq

Given a List of Vectors, how can I efficiently Select all of the greatest values of a property, among all members who share other values among different properties.

For example, with the standard Vector3, how would I choose the Vector3s who have the largest Y value relative to all other members with identical X and Z values.

My current working method, is to iterate through the list like so:

```cs
Vector3 current = Vector3.Zero;
List<Vector3> out = new List<Vector3>();
foreach(var member in MyList)
{
    current= member;
    foreach(var compare in MyList)
    {
        if(!predicate(current,compare))
            current = compare;
    }
    out.Add(largest);
}
```

But this doesn't seem particularly efficient, as it performs n squared comparisons, where n is the length of the list.

Any suggestions on cutting this down to a more workable number, as I intend to use this in a performance critical section of my code.

For the predicate of equal X and Z values, the greatest value of Y

Example Input:

```
(1,1,1)
(1,2,1)
(1,4,1)
(2,3,2)
(2,5,2)
(1,4,2)
(1,2,2)
(1,1,2)
(2,5,1)
(2,4,1)
(2,9,1)
```

Expected Output:

```
(1,4,1)
(2,5,2)
(1,4,2)
(2,9,1)
```

Comment: why don't you use linq?

Comment: And please can you add an example, as input and what do you except as an output

Comment: I have it written out without LINQ the long way. I don't know a way to condense this with LINQ, hence the question

Comment: In your example, what's `predicate`?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish example in and out added

Comment: Do you want to take the X largest values?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No, I want the largest Y with X and Z being the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
var result = vectors
    .GroupBy(v => Tuple.Create(v.X, v.Z))
    .Select(vg => vg.OrderByDescending(v => v.Y).First())
    .ToList();
```

- The `GroupBy` will use a Tuple of `X` and `Z` as a key.
- From each group, we `Select` the value with the largest `Y` value.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/LQC74954)

Comment: Very nice! I loved the idea.

Comment: Just one question about this, is GroupBy more efficient behind the scenes than what i have set up, performing n^2 comparisons?

Comment: @Azeranth the example you gave in the question doesn't actually return the same list as you "expect", so I can't really accurately compare for time.